# How to change color in a range of cells using an Axtive X control button?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

I am attempting to use an Active X control button to change the background (fill) color of a range of cells when the button is clicked and then change it back to its original color when clicked again. The code I have returns errors. I am looking for a simple solution.

Basic Idea:

```
   Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    If Intersect(target, Range("M3, 03:Z3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        If target.Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(252, 228, 214) Then
            target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        ElseIf target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
            target.Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(252, 228, 214)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: `target` is an undeclared variable. `"M3, 03:Z3"` is not a valid address. `.Color`, not `.ColorIndex`, should be used with `RGB`.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I am not sure how to list the cells I wish to target as a valid address, or declared variable. I am attempting to skip the cell "N3" in the row range of M3 through Z3, while including all other cells in that range as the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim c As Range
    With Me.Range("M3,O3:Z3")
        Set c = .Cells(1)  'assuming all cells in the range of interest have the same color?
        If c.Interior.Color = RGB(252, 228, 214) Then
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Me.Range("J3").Value = "Some text"
        ElseIf c.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
            .Interior.Color = RGB(252, 228, 214)
            Me.Range("J3").ClearContents
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: With the last issue solved, I am wondering how to add a second function onto the above code to add text to cell J3 using the same color references as above. 

 If c.Interior.Color = RGB(252, 228, 214) Then
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
ADD>  .Range("J3").Value = "Text Here"          (**Problem: Range is already defined)

and

ElseIf c.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
            .Interior.Color = RGB(252, 228, 214)
ADD>  .Range("J3").Value = ""                           (**Problem: Range is already defined)

Without causing a loop reference to the range of cells mentioned above.

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: Tim Williams, you did it again. Exactly what I needed. Thank you, your help has been invaluable. I really appreciate the help you have given me today.